# Getting terms to have space between them

Tags: terms

I am trying to show a list of terms that a post is located in. Within the admin it is showing posts in more than one term such as Mixed, Office. My issue is that with the code that I am using it is putting the into my templet but is placing the right next to each other and now adding space between them so it would look like Mixedoffice The code I am using is below. Thank you for any help on this.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($property['ID'], 'property_sub_type');

if(!empty($terms)){

    foreach($terms as $value){

        echo $value->name;

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either concatenate your call to echo with a space or newline.

**Space:**

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($property['ID'], 'property_sub_type');

if(!empty($terms)){

    foreach($terms as $value){

        echo $value->name . " ";

    }

}

?>
```

**Newline:**

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($property['ID'], 'property_sub_type');

if(!empty($terms)){

    foreach($terms as $value){

        echo $value->name . "\n";

    }

}

?>
```